# Trying to calculate pi, but my code is really slow

Tags: python, pi

I'm making a program that approximates pi. When I try to approximate more than six or seven digits, the code takes a lot of time to run. What can I do to improve this code?

When I try to enter more than 10 million in the range it gets really slow.
Is my way of doing it just chronically slow?

```py
nx = 0

for i in range(1000):
    x, y = ((-1)**(i)), i*2+1
    nx = (x*(1/y) + nx)

print(nx * 4)
```

Comment: Your code simply is slow and will take some time. There are faster ways to calculate pi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm

Comment: Also for further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is nothing meaningfully wrong with the code. It simply should be expected to take a long time, because it is not actually a good way of calculating pi, just one that works in theory and is relatively easy to explain in math textbooks.

Comment: A loop that executes 10M times will **obviously** be slower than a loop that executes 1K times.  I honestly don't understand the question.

Comment: What is your definition of "chronically slow"? Maybe your computer is just too slow for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to enter more than 10 million in the range it gets really slow

When I enter exactly 10 million, it takes a bit less than 3.8 seconds. 100 million - 38 seconds.

As the comments pointed out, the method is generally slow.

However, there are some places where you can improve your code:

1. `(-1)**i` - for humans, we can get the result instantly based on parity of `i`. For computer, it has to calculate the power over and over again. Solution: make the new value be minus previous value. Or just check parity of `i`.

   After fixing it, for 100 million iterations I get around 13 seconds. That's almost 3x less than your original solution.
2. `i*2+1` is not too bad, but it's just previous value+2. If you want to get into really high values of `i`, this small detail might make a difference.

   For 100 million iterations, it further improved time measured, to 8 seconds. 10^9 iterations completed after 1.5 minutes.
3. [point added after edit] I also changed `x*(1/y)` which is two operations into just `x/y`. I think (and timings below suggest it) that I did it between points 1 and 2.

After those two fixes:

```py
def pi(irange):
  nx = 0
  x = -1
  y = -1
  for i in range(irange):
    x, y = -x, y+2
    nx += x/y
  print(nx * 4)
```

(I made it a parametrized function for quicker adjustment of range)

Note: the timings were done manually with datetime. I am currently running timeit for more accurate times.

---

Timeit results below.

Original function:

- 10^7 range 100 repeats: 384.64436824899167 (average: 3.8464436824899167 per run)
- 10^8 range 10 repeats: 384.61059385107365 (average: 38.461059385107365 per run)
- 10^9 range 10 repeats: 4072.4737908249954 (average: 407.24737908249954 = 6 minutes and 47 seconds per run!)

All fixes (code above):

- 10^7 range 100 repeats: 80.37718613096513 (average: 0.8037718613096513 per run - less than 1s!)
- 10^8 range 10 repeats: 80.44559745094739 (average: 8.044559745094739 per run)
- 10^9 range 5 repeats: 825.6300983070396 (average: 82.56300983070396 per run)

That gives us around 4.8 times faster code

---

For completeness sake:

Point 3 (`x*(1/y)` -> `x/y`) fix only; after I was almost done with timings and noticed I didn't list this change above:

- 10^8 range 10 repeats: 355.2653473580722

Point 1 fix only:

- 10^8 range 10 repeats: 127.73778830398805

Point 2 fix only:

- 10^8 range 10 repeats: 356.37889020494185

Point 1 & 3 fixes:

- 10^8 range 10 repeats: 102.76280109107029

Point 2 & 3 fixes:

- 10^8 range 10 repeats: 327.99749922403134

[Note that even with the repeats, of course load on my computer could change the result. I wasn't that motivated to whip the tests on another machine, I just left them on one console while I was doing other stuff.]

Comment: crazy to think that in the 80s, it took almost 7 hours to calculate 8 million digits.

Comment: @JonSG Please note: the number of iterations for this method is not the same as amount of digits of pi it approximates. 10^9 iterations only give a result of 3.1415926525880504 - so only 8 accurate digits after decimal point.